# Is it necessary to logarithm continuous attributes, when tree construction is histogram powered?

Tags: boosting, gradient, h2o

[LightGBM wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/wiki/Features) says:

> LightGBM uses the histogram based algorithms, which bucketing continuous feature(attribute) values into discrete bins, to speed up training procedure and reduce memory usage.

With this approach, if my continuous feature has a power distribution, most observations will fall into the first few bins, when in the others, there will be only a few values.

So my question is:

**Is it necessary to logarithm continuous attributes, when tree construction is histogram based?**

Answer (score 2):

No and yes: The bins should ideally be adapted to the distribution, such that each bin contains (approximately) an equal number of observations. Doing a log transform and then following up with uniform binning is a good approximation for exponentially distributed values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Gradient boosting is good because it allows you to get good baselines, without going into the nature of the data. Therefore, intuition dictates that it is best to break into Bins by quantiles. Therefore, the question to you, as to the developer `h20`: why you have implemented so many options and for what purposes they can be more preferable (or how `AUTO` works, schematically)?


http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-turnbull/1/docs-website/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/histogram_type.html